Incompatibility problem between matplotlib and Python
I am using Matplotlib version 3.7.2. My Python version in Anaconda's Spyder is 3.8.18. When I run the line
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I get the error module matplotlib has no attribute rcParams. When I try to upgrade the Matplotlib and matplotlib.base packages from the current 3.7.2 version to 3.8 or 3.8.4, I get the following error message:
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

What should I do? I would appreciate any help
I expect Matplotlib to work smoothly

I would suggest you upgrade your python version because matplotlib 3.8 supports Python 3.9 - 3.12.
